# Jquery 1.6.2 Doesnt work with datatype : json

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I'm making a signup form in which i've used following function for validate signup this function is called when a form is attempted to submit.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "view/ajax/php/checkcap.php",
    data: $('#capform').serialize(),
    dataType: "json",
    async: false,
    success: function(msg){
        alert(msg.txt);
        // other validations
    }
})
```

here alert is just for display response from checkcap.php file. it works perfectly with jquery 1.3.2 however i've upgraded the jquery 1.3.2 to 1.6.2. after using jquery 1.6.2, however function gets response from the php file (checked using firebug) but can't display the message (response from php file). how to make the code work with jquery 1.6.2 ?

Comment: Does the `alert` actually come up? Otherwise your request could be failing, you'd check the errors, instead of the success callback-hook.

Comment: Are you sure you're not getting errors? Use a JS console and see. Looks like some semicolon is missing there

Comment: no i've put alert for just debug the php response. there is no any errors in the code as i've checked

Comment: Why is async false? Also, try doing `alert(JSON.stringify(msg))` to see if you're getting what you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make sure the json format is

```
{
  "one": "Singular sensation",
  "two": "Beady little eyes",
  "three": "Little birds pitch by my doorstep"
}
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

You are missing double quotes on propertynames

```
{"status":0,"txt":"a"}   ---correct
{status:0,txt:"a"}       ---wrong
```

Comment: yes the same format i've used data: $('#capform').serialize(), it will make this type of format to post data to php

Comment: use firebug and tell the response you are getting from server

Comment: this response firebug is getting '{status:0,txt:"a"}' from that php file

Comment: status and text should be inside double quotes!!

Comment: or this if form validated as true'{status:1,txt:"success"}' and if form is not valid then '{status:0,txt:"failed"}'.

Comment: you are missing double quotes

Comment: plz give example as u said ( status and txt in quote )

Comment: great !!! thank you very much for your support, it worked. you saved my time. by the way even i didn't think of this.